# How to Avoid FOUC- Flash of Unstyled Content in angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, fouc

What is the best way to avoid FOUC in angular 2 and above? Is there any alternative of ng-cloak in angular 2 versions.
I have research on this, but couldn't found any satisfying way to prevent FOUC.

Comment: I have never experienced a FOUC in Angular (v2+). What browser do you use ?

Comment: I have tested on chrome. I think that everything that are bind using the double curly brackets {{}}  is potentially displayed before loading the styles.

Comment: Hmm... How do you serve your Angular application ? Do you experience the same thing if you create a new Angular project using the Angular CLI ?

Comment: the problem is when a template paints a data model showing some content which gets temporarily cleared while async loading new content. The view goes from show-A to flash of show-empty to show-B.